# Select the lowest price by item in SQL with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, min

I have multiple tables representing Flights data :

flights :

```
ID | NMB   | DATE
1  | CA1   | 2017-05-26
2  | CA1   | 2017-05-27
3  | CA2   | 2017-05-26
4  | CA2   | 2017-05-27
```

airports :

```
ID | NAME
1  | JFK
2  | LAX
```

flights_arrival :

```
ENTITY_ID (flights) | TARGET_ID (airports)
1                   | 1
2                   | 1
3                   | 2
4                   | 2
```

flights_price :

```
ENTITY_ID (flights) | VALUE
1                   | 455
2                   | 650
3                   | 750
4                   | 880
```

I'm trying to select the lowest price for each flight for each airport of arrival. What I want is this :

```
ID | ARRIVAL | PRICE
1  | 1       | 455
3  | 2       | 750
```

This is the SQL query I constructed but the `MIN` function applied on the `flights_price` does not return only the lowest price for the flight but all entries :

```
        SELECT
            f.id AS id,
            fa.target_id AS arrival,
            MIN(fp.value) AS price
        FROM flights_price AS fp
        JOIN flights AS f ON fp.entity_id=f.id
        JOIN flights_arrival AS fa ON fa.entity_id=f.id
        WHERE
          fa.target_id IN (1, 2)
        GROUP BY
          fa.target_id,
          fp.value,
          f.id;
```

What I am doing wrong ? I also tried subqueries with no success.

Comment: As a rule, one groups by the thing one selects. If the billion or so answers to similar questions here don't help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: what `ARRIVAL` column here be belongs to which table column

Comment: `ARRIVAL` belongs to `flights_arrival` aliased by `fa`.

Answer (score 0):

You have `value` column in `GROUP BY`, if you need to apply an aggregate column on it, you need to remove it from `GROUP BY` (otherwise it will be applied on only one value per group only, making the aggregation redundant), e.g.:

```
SELECT fa.entity_id, f.name, fa.target_id, a.name, MIN(value)
FROM flights_arrival fa JOIN flights_price fp ON fa.entity_id = fp.flights
JOIN flights f ON fa.entity_id = f.id
JOIN airports a ON fa.target_id = a.id
WHERE fa.target_id IN (1,2)
GROUP BY fa.entity_id, f.name, fa.target_id, a.name;
```

Comment: If I remove `fp.value` from the `GROUP BY` I get the error: `Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #3 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY`

Answer (score 0):

Try this query -

```
SELECT fp.entity_id AS id, target_id AS arrival, MIN(value) AS price    
FROM flights_arrival AS fa
INNER JOIN flights_price AS fp ON (fp.entity_id = fa.entity_id)
GROUP BY target_id;
```

From your output and your tried query, I am guessing that you need only the flights which have arrivals and price. That is why there is no need to use the flights table. You can also add the WHERE filter before the group by to get results for specific ids rather than all flights.

The entity_id column could be in the **SELECT** statement even though it is not present in the **GROUP BY** since the db is **MySQL**. Also as in *flights_price* table the **entity_id** is unique, therefore **fp.entity_id** will get the correct value for the min price.

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c3ad6c/1)

Comment: The query you are suggesting does not work. Whenever you `GROUP BY` on a selected field in a request, you must use `GROUP BY` on the other selected fields. Doing otherwise, SQL will throw a `Syntax error of ORDER BY clause` exception. In this case, we must have a `GROUP BY` expression on the `fp.value` and `fp.entity_id` fields. But you made a point saying that I don't need the flight table at all, that's true and I continue testing request without it.

Comment: You are using MySQL right? MySQL (5.9) allows selecting columns that are not in group by statement.

Please see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c3ad6c/1). If you are not using MySQL the query won't work.

Comment: Yes I'm using MySQL (5.7.17) but the query does not work, I'm getting `GROUP BY` exceptions, maybe I'm doing something wrong. Your Fiddle works, thanks for putting it out there. I will continue to work on it.

Comment: Let me know how it goes. I am also interested to see why you are getting that exception.